# Change the color of the cell to red if the value in the Database is empty

Tags: vba, excel

I have developed Excel Macros, Which fetches the data from the database. I want to change the color of the cell if the value in the database is empty. I have this code. But the below code  does not work.

```
If Not rs.EOF Then
For n = 0 To rs.Fields.Count - 1
   objSheet.Cells(iRow, iCol).Value = rs.Fields.Item(n)
         If UCase(rs.Fields.Item(n).Name) = "ORDER_STATUS" Then
            If UCase(rs.Fields.Item(n)) = "" Then
                objSheet.Cells(iRow, iCol).Interior.ColorIndex = 3
                  Else
                   objSheet.Cells(iRow, iCol).Interior.ColorIndex = 4
                    End If
                      End If
```

Comment: What doesn't work?  Have you tried stepping through your code in the VBA editor (with F8)?  I think that will reveal what is going wrong.

Comment: If the value is not empty i get green color but if the value is empty or blank its does not set to Colorindex 3. Any help is appreciated

Comment: Then step up to the line with the = "" check, pause it there, and put this in the Immediate window: Debug.Print rs.Fields.Item(n)    <enter>

Comment: when the value is Empty rs.EOF is true. and its not stepping to For loop so  Is there any way I can do if rs is empty I can change the cell to red

Answer (score 0):

Try the same code in reverse..

```
If UCase(rs.Fields.Item(n)) <> "" Then
    objSheet.Cells(iRow, iCol).Interior.ColorIndex = 4
    Else
    objSheet.Cells(iRow, iCol).Interior.ColorIndex = 3
End If
```

Hope this will help you :)

Comment: rs.EOF is true and its exiting the if loop and not reaching For so the reverse code could not help me – if the value is empty rs. EOF is true